# How can I define a polygon entity using availability intervals in Cesium?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cesiumjs

I am defining a realy huge polygon that changes its position and shape using inertial reference frame.

First, I tryed to define a set of CZML polygons, each one with an availability and its coordinates like the "california" object in [this sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=CZML%20Polygon%20-%20Intervals%2C%20Availability.html), but this exceeds the maximum memory limit and blocks the browser and eventually the computer.
Then, I had it working using only one polygon in CZML providing a list with an interval and the polygon shape coordinates, like the "dynamicPolygon" in [the same sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=CZML%20Polygon%20-%20Intervals%2C%20Availability.html).

Now I am trying to change the CZML implementation to use entities but the [entity](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Entity.html) documentation allows to use a [PolygonGraphics](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PolygonGraphics.html) that allows to use a [Property](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Property.html) or a [PolygonHierarchy](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PolygonHierarchy.html) to configure the shape, and I can not figure out how to do the same "dynamicPolygon" using entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CallbackProperty` (that is a type of `Property`) in the hierarchy constructor option. There should not be issues with memory due to there is only one object and the positions are being calculated dynamically. You also can use a collection like `TimeIntervalCollectionProperty` and then ask for the value for an specific time.

Try to add the next code fragment in the [Hello World Cesium sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?label=Beginner):

```
viewer.entities.add({
    id: "dynamicPolygon",
    name: "dynamicPolygon",
    polygon: new Cesium.PolygonGraphics({
      hierarchy: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function (time, result) {
        var n = time.secondsOfDay%10;
        result = new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy([
            Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(2*n, n),
            Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-2*n, n),
            Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-2*n, -n),
            Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(2*n, -n)
        ]);
        return result;
      }, false),
      material: Cesium.Color.WHITE
  })
});
```